# Bitcoin unconfirmed trasection to cancel

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, blockchain.info

I am new to bitcoin. i use blockchain. info.
i sent vtc to a purse on 15.12.17, but i am stuck still there after 20days.
i determined to cancel the reanection. 
please help me.
Transection ID: https://blockchain.info/tx/2bd29e84967f6ee9c392b8bb8cb4cadb7e1560604f92dfbd57d88268b6c99714

please help me to cancel this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to 'cancel' a published transaction. After you publish a transaction to the network, all of the nodes will relay your transaction, so that eventually they (should) all know of your transaction. If you tried to publish a 'cancel request', you would have no guarantee that every single node would hear about that request, and even if they did, they may not be incentivized to listen to it. So 'cancelling' a transaction is not part of the protocol.

Your transaction included a low fee, and so it has not yet confirmed. Eventually, the network's nodes may all 'forget' about your transaction, so you could then re-spend the coins to an address you control. [Take a look at this question for more info on unconfirmed transactions.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: still unconfirmed, pending....

Answer (score -1):

You can not `cancel` transaction.

Next time do not put your funds in the technology you do not understand. 0.00561718 BTC - is not a significant amount paid for a knowledge.

Comment: i wanted to pay from a marchant website. then after payment, its stuck. please help to recover. (cancel/payment confirmation)

Comment: still not reached, pending......